# Wordpress site shows blank Index page after messing with apache

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I am new to EC2 and was dealing with SSL installation for my WP website. I had something wrong and website was showing default Apache web page. Then I deleted index.html file to bring back my WP site. It didn't work either.

I need some assistance on how to show my WP site when enter my domain on address box.

Site URL: www.infinity-vr.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your files are in correct directory. I don't see the Apache web page.

Comment: I ran the code to delete the index.html file on /var/www/html/index.html. Then it shows the empty directory. I need help on what to do to show my wp site directory.

Comment: are your wp files in /var/www/html directory?

Comment: Nope. /var/www/html directory is empty now. How should I carry all my wp files to that directory?

Comment: Now, I moved WP files to /var/www/html. But the site shows directory not  the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

In Bitnami, we put all the configuration files of apache inside of `/opt/bitami/apps/wordpress/conf`.
We have explained all this configuration in our docs webpage:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws

Regarding the info you need:

Uploading the ssl certificates to your wordpress server:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/#how-to-upload-files-to-the-server-with-sftp

Enabling https with your ssl certificates:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/#how-to-enable-https-support-with-ssl-certificates

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks David. But my question was about carrying my wp files to empty html directory. For the SSL certification I am planning to use WP Plugin.